# 2D FFT of a plane wave with changing spatial frequencies

Tags: fft

I was trying to simulate the frequency spectrum of a 2D tilted plane wave with changing spatial frequencies (looks like a grating). According to the property of 2D FFT: `FFT(exp(j*2pi*(ax+by)))=δ(fX-a, fY-b)` , if we change the frequency component a and b step by step, its FFT (looks like a focus spot) is supposed to scan in the spectrum plane.

The raster scanning of the focus spot is wanted. However, it looks like the scanning behaves not as wanted, although a and b changes in a two for-loop way. The attached gif[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efEny.gif) only shows a few frames of the simulation and you can run the attached code for complete result.

It seems that the actual center frequency of the grating should be consistent with the sampling frequency used here? Has anyone could help me to figure it out? Thanks in advance.

```
input_dim = 50;
input_num = input_dim^2;

[u, v] = meshgrid(1:input_dim, 1:input_dim);   

Su = 1/input_dim:1/input_dim:1;  %sampling frequency
Sv =  1/input_dim:1/input_dim:1;
                                       

%% Grating: tilted plane wave

figure('position', [200 250,1000 400]),
G = zeros(input_dim, input_dim, input_num);

for i = 1:input_num
    [fvi, fui] = ind2sub([input_dim, input_dim], i); 
   
    G(:, :, i) = exp(1i * (fui*u + fvi*v));
    F_G = fft2(G(:, :, i));
    subplot(121), imagesc(1:input_dim, 1:input_dim, real(G(:, :, i))), colormap(gray)
    subplot(122), imagesc(Su, Sv, abs(F_G)), colormap(gray)
    
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: Now I have answer for that, this is really a tricky question! The problem is indeed due to the mismatch between the spatial frequency of the grating and the sampling frequency at spectrum plane. We know the spatial frequency of the grating is (fui/2π, fvi/2π) while the spectrum sampling frequency is in the interval of (0, 1). Due to such mismatch, the moving of the center frequency of the grating's spectrum is not in a normal way in the sampling grid.

Comment: But if we take a closer look, we can find it is actually doing raster scanning! The multiple scanning along one column is merely because the true spatial frequency is larger than the sampling frequency at spectrum plane, and after that, the focus spot does move to the next column, while not in the starting row as expected.

Comment: Let's define a scaling factor for matching spatial frequency with spectrum sampling frequency, ```scale = 1 / input_dim;``` and change the code of generating grating to ```G(:, :, i) = exp(1i * 2 * pi * scale * (fui*u + fvi*v));```, then we can see the spatial frequency of the grating is also in the interval of (0, 1), then the moving of the center frequency of the grating's spectrum is in a good raster scanning way.